# Filehelpers ExcelStorage read template from resources

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource, filehelpers

`Filehelpers ExcelStorage` has a property `public string TemplateFile { get; set; }`

For that reason I have to keep my template file in the program directory (bin).
But if I want to use my template file as a embedded resource is there any way I can still use that as a template in `ExcelStorage` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `TemplateFile` property is for specifying the *.xls* file to use when writing data, not for the record class.

However, you ought to be able to use [Runtime Record Classes](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/runtime_classes.html). Something like:

```
// myTemplate is the extracted resource as a string
string mClass = myTemplate;
Type t = ClassBuilder.ClassFromString(mClass); 
var storage = new ExcelStorage(t);
//etc.
```